# Passing value between files in Vue without node/npm

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to setup basic prototype web pages to test UX design in code. And want to recycle html files such as left navigation. Trying to use Vue to do this so that I can also learn Vue. I do not have access to the artifactory (company policy). So I cannot use things other than this http vue loader package that I found. So far, I was able to add external vue which is comp-nav. But from here, I want to pass title="Service" from index.html to comp-vue. How do I do that? Any help would be great! BTW, using Apache2 that came with mac to run.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <title>App</title>

  <!-- Vue2 -->

  <!-- from https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader -->

  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/http-vue-loader"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <comp-nav title="Service"></comp-nav>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: {
          'comp-nav': httpVueLoader('components/comp-nav.vue')
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

components/comp-nav.vue

```
<template>
<div id="nav">
    <div class="nav-header">
        <div class="header-title"><a>{{ title }}</a></div>
        <div class="header-close">U</div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-body">
        <ul>
            <li>Link 1</li>
            <li>Link 2</li>
            <li>Link 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><!-- #nav -->
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [example from the docs](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader#examples), you could [define a component `prop`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) in `comp-nav.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div class="header-title">{{ title }}</div>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  props: ['title']
}
</script>
```